# does python have a comma operator like C

Tags: python

in C (and C family of languages) an expression `(4+7, 5+2)` returns `7`. But the same expression in Python would result in a tuple `(11, 7)`

So does python have a comma operator like C ?

Comment: No, but the real question is why you'd want one

Comment: Beautiful is better than ugly.
    Sparse is better than dense.
    Readability counts.

Comment: If Python has that useless comma operator then I don't believe anymore Python is readable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use something like this to replace it:

```
comma_operated = (4+7, 5+2)[-1]
```

but as noted correctly in the comments, why would you want it? It is used in C or C++ quite seldomly and there are good reasons for that.

Comment: nice :)
actually, it's useful to debug a list comprehension : you can execute a print in the comprehension to see what's going on

Comment: I am using it to insert a temporary debug output statement without a major rewrite.

Comment: It is by no means surprising that people need it. There are places where only *expressions* are allowed (in contrast to statements) like list comprehension, within an assertion statement, etc. This would allow evaluating arbitrary expressions within an expression. A method verify() that throws an exception in case of error, running methods with side effects, etc.

Comment: Well, e.g. for pandas, this is _quite_ useful: `.... .pipe(lambda x: [display(my_expression(x)), x][-1])` in order to output diagnostics and then continue with the original `x`.

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK, no. Though you can always simulate this by using two lines instead of one. :-)

```
x = (call_one(), call_two())

# is almost the same as

call_one()
x = call_two()

# or
x = (call_one(), call_two())[1]
```

Comment: No you can't. See my comment ("It is by no means surprising that people need it") to @KillianDS's answer.

Answer (score 2):

An update to this question.

As it stands the accepted answer is incomplete since it does not allow assignment expressions to be used in this manner, (e.g. `(a = 1, a+2)[-1]` would generate an error).

Python 3.8 is now coming up with [Assignment Expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) which in theory should make this possible, i.e.

```
( a := 1, a + 2)[-1]
```